# Django Clear All Admin List Filters

Tags: python, django, list

I have a Django admin control panel and in each list of objects there are lots and lots of list filters. I want to be able to clear all the filters with a click of a button, but can't find where this ability is, if it already exists in Django.

Routes I'm considering (but cannot figure out):

1. Make the last item in the breadcrumb link to the full list
2. Make a direct hyperlink as a filter list option
3. Find some way to access all the query options and remove them or simply return a blank one (queryset.all() isn't working; I'm probably barking up the wrong tree.)
4. That kind of thing should already exist! Find out how to use it.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this? I've been trying to figure it out all day.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least one entry in `search_fields` and therefore are showing a search box on your admin changelist page, if you have any filters or search terms in effect you should see information to the right of it showing the number of rows that match your current filter and search criteria.  It'll be worded as something like "5 results (50 total)".  The "50 total" text will be a link to an unfiltered version of the list, showing the whole set.  Possibly paginated, but all filters will be cleared.

This doesn't appear to be automatically exposed without the search box.  The filter settings are simple arguments in the URL querystring, so it should be easy to add a link similar to the one in the search box that just drops the querystring, but you'd have to learn a little about the admin templates to do so.  Setting a `search_fields` entry is probably simpler, if you have anything reasonable to search over.